# "Please don't be" after "I'm sorry"

Tags: grammar, ellipsis

I'd like to know if "please don't be" is properly used in the following:

> M: The book was quite hard for him. He spent a whole year reading it.

> W: Oops, I’m sorry ...

> M: **Please don’t be.** He really enjoyed the book. And he learned a lot of new words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's used correctly. The word "sorry" is elided from

> Please don't be sorry.

Comment: Do you thbk that "oops" is natural there?

Comment: It's a natural thing to say in some contexts. For example, imagining that W feels he inadvertently suggested too long and difficult a book for M's "he", it does seem natural.